# Why does this simple recursive tree traversal algorithm fail?

Tags: python, tree, nested, generator, traversal

I've written a recursive algorithm to traverse nested iterators in Python. I don't understand why it succeeds in printing out the elements, but fails to yield them as a generator.

While I have managed to print out the elements:

```
tree = [[1,2],[3,[['abcde',['f']],'gh']]]

def traverse_printing(parent): 
     try: 
         for child in parent: 
              traverse(child) 
     except TypeError: 
         print(parent) 

>>> traverse_printing(tree)                                                                                                                                                                                    
1
2
3
a
b
c
...
```

I am struggling to turn it into a generator.

```
def traverse(parent): 
     try: 
         for child in parent: 
              traverse(child) 
     except TypeError: 
         yield parent
```

`traverse(tree)` currently does not work. The result is:

```
>>> list(traverse(tree))                                                                                                                                                                              
[]
```

The expected result would be `[1,2,3,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']`

Why is it the case? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

`traverse` returns a generator object. Thus, on the `traverse` call, you have to loop over the returned result and yield each value or utilize the statement `yield from` :

```
for child in parent: 
   yield from traverse(child)
```

However, your current solution fails with a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` because you are only catching the occurrence of iteration over an integer value (which raises a `TypeError`). Looping over a string is a valid operation in Python, hence the infinite recursive calls. Thus you will need to check the actual types of `parent`:

```
def traverse(parent): 
  if isinstance(parent, str):
     yield from parent
  elif isinstance(parent, int):
     yield parent
  else: 
     for child in parent: 
        yield from traverse(child) 

list(traverse(tree))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: This was very helpful! To keep it simple and type agnostic, I just added another except clause `except RecursionError:  yield parent` and it worked like a charm. Thanks